# squid configuration for whataspp

Tags: proxy, squid

I'm running Ubuntu server 14.04 I successfully installed squid3.5 via apt-get and I configured it to allow all proxy requests by changing the default configuration file like the following:

I changed this line

```
http_access deny all
```

to

```
http_access allow all
```

then I configured my mobile to use this proxy and I was able to browse all website, but when it comes to Whatsapp it's not sending any message.

What should I change in the configuration file to make Whatsapp works?

Comment: This setting will allow _anyone_ who can reach your proxy to use it. If it's accessible from the Internet it _will_ get found, and you will likely be held responsible for any attacks channeled through your proxy. Just sayin'.

Comment: thank you, I will update it shortly but now just for testing to make sure nothing effect the connection

Answer (score 0):

Hope you configure proxy on your phone using WiFi configuration pane. By configuring proxy there you cannot send all application data via that forward proxy. (And newer android version show warning about this as I remember). That's not the way squid forward proxy works. this will work for simple web browsing where browser directly talk to the proxy. But when it comes to the application level those have more freedom to decide how  to connect to the internet.  If you really need to send whatsapp traffic through proxy try squid transparent proxy + SSL proxy combination and redirect the  whatsapp traffic using DNS or iptables.